# Will changing my array type to Int16 save storage?

Tags: c++, arrays, types

This is the first time I'm working with large data sets in C++. Before, I'd just store whatever I want to in arrays. Because I'm generating heightmaps of 4000x4000 now, I want to be a bit more memory efficient, before my program is suddenly gulping up 100 MB (a little exorbitant for an indie fellow like me).

I'm going to load most of the data in chunks, but because my program needs a large amount of the data during execution, I'll still end up with large 2D-arrays in use. I want to find a way to make them occupy very little memory.

My heightmap is designed so that it only takes on small integer values; possibly small enough to fit into an `Int8` but at the very least small enough for a `Int16`. So far, I've been using `Int` types, which on my implementation are of the `Int32` variety.

If I were to switch my 2D-arrays and vectors to sets of the `Int16` type, would this save me half the storage? Or would one element of the array still take one full byte and simply leave those untouched bits at zero?

Comment: not sure which `Int16` you mean, but I would expect it to occupy 2 bytes, not less than one. What "untouched bits" do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

Switching to `Int16` (assuming this is the same as `int16_t`) from `Int32` (assuming this is the same as `int32_t`) would bring down the memory consumption that stems from your array by half (not considering any bookkeeping that goes along with the possibly dynamically sized array)

Also `int16_t` takes 2 bytes, and `int32_t` takes 4 bytes.  The `16_t` implies 16 bits.

There are no untouched bits, only those which you chose to not use at runtime.  [Unlike some pointer types](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/DiscriminatedPtr.h), there are no unused bits with integers.  0s and 1s give identity to the integer's value

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about the **fixed-width integer types**, then yes *int16_t* is guaranteed to be 16 bits without padding bits. You may also verify this yourself:

```
std::cout << sizeof(int16_t[1000]) << " " << sizeof(int32_t[1000]);
```